How can I write Bengali words without affecting any other font of my article?
I want to write Bengali words and phrases within my English article in LaTeX. However, the problem is that whenever I try to use any package for Bengali, it immediately changes the English font of my article. When I use \usepackage{bangla} or \usepackage{fontspec} or \usepackage{polyglossia}, the English font changes right away, even without writing another line. I have tried various solutions found online, but none have worked. Some suggested setting the main font to Times New Roman, but that does not match the style of my article. I tried using "\showthe\font" and got the output "> \TU/lmr/m/n/10.95," but I still couldn't fix the issue. How can I write Bengali words without affecting any other font of my article? For example, the sentence "... an accurate translation would be 'সে এখন কোথায়?'. This is the...". I tried compiler pdfLatex, XeLatex, and LuaLatex.

There are already many discussions regarding this topic on this site. Please search with the keyword Bengali.

You select the main language (English, in the example) and the secondary one (Bengali, in the example). You can select a different font for the secondary language and segregate the parts you need in Bengali:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}

\newfontfamily{\bengalifont}{Bangla MN} % or any Bengali font you have

\begin{document}

An accurate translation of \textbengali{সে এখন কোথায়?} 
would be ``where is he now?''

\begin{otherlanguage}{bengali}
সে এখন কোথায়?
\end{otherlanguage}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{bengali}
সে এখন কোথায়?
\end{otherlanguage*}

\begin{bengali}
সে এখন কোথায়?
\end{bengali}

\end{document}

\textbengali{<text>} is for short inline parts in Bengali.
\begin{otherlanguage}{bengali} is for long parts at the level, say, of chapters.
\begin{otherlanguage*}{bengali} is for paragraphs in Bengali, for instance an abstract.
\begin{bengali} is a shorthand for the otherlanguage* environment.


Thanks for the answer but this also changes the English font. Would you kindly check it?

@NahidHossainShihab No, it doesn't. The English font is the standard one; if you want a different font, select it with \setmainfont.

Babel supports Bengali, too. The following example works with luatex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{bangla}
\babelfont[bangla]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

 ... an accurate translation would be 'সে এখন কোথায়?'. This is the...

\end{document}



Thanks for the answer but this also changes the English font.  Would you kindly check it?

The English font has not changed at all. It's still the default one.
